# What is the best way to capture Camera and Mic from browser and stream it to a RTMP server?

Tags: webrtc, rtmp

So I am trying to figure out what is the best way to capture Camera and Mic from browser and them stream it to a RTMP Server. The idea is after the transfer to the RTMP server to restream it back to the client side of the app.

An example would be:

1. User opens the browser and allow access to camera and mic, then I capture this using webrtc.
2. The signal goes to the RTMP server and is returned back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Browsers are limited in the prtocaly they support. Http/websockets, and WebRTC are the only options. no RTMP.

You will need a server in the middle to receive one of these protocols and convert to RTMP.